# compare two csv file Python

Tags: python

I have two csv files.. I want to compare second column of file1 with third column and then print matched in outputfile

file1.csv

A0AUZ9  ENSP00000281772

A0AUZ9  ENSP00000405724

A0AUZ9  ENSP00000401408

A0AUZ9  ENSP00000393432

A0AVK6  ENSP00000250024

A0AVK6  ENSP00000434199

A0AVT1  ENSP00000313454

A0AVT1  ENSP00000399234

A0JNW5  ENSP00000279907

file2.csv

meNOG13950  9606    ENSP00000305973 1   264

meNOG14003  9606    ENSP00000281772 1   987

meNOG14125  9606    ENSP00000346414 1   624

meNOG06168  9606    ENSP00000287936 1   888

meNOG06177  9606    ENSP00000313454 1   1052

meNOG06177  9606    ENSP00000333266 1   1012

outputfile.txt

meNOG14003  9606    ENSP00000281772 1   987

meNOG06177  9606    ENSP00000313454 1   1052

thanks

Comment: It'd be nice to see what you've tried, and what you've put effort into. Don't expect much effort from the community if you haven't put forth any.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this:

```
import csv
with open('file1.csv') as f1, open('file2.csv') as f2:
    reader1, reader2 = [csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ') for f in [f1,f2]]
    m1 = {row[1]:row for row in reader1}
    m2 = {row[2]:row for row in reader2}
    intersect = set(m1.keys()) & set(m2.keys())
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:
        writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=' ')
        for k in intersect:
            writer.writerow(m2[k])
```

output:

```
$ cat output.txt
meNOG14003 9606 ENSP00000281772 1 987
meNOG06177 9606 ENSP00000313454 1 1052
```

Comment: Try this code in python 2.6.4 & 2.7.3 and both returns "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compare3.py", line 4, in <module>
    m1 = {row[1]:row for row in reader1}
  File "compare3.py", line 4, in <dictcomp>
    m1 = {row[1]:row for row in reader1}
IndexError: list index out of range
"  May I know which version of python you might use? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where's your code...

```
def do_work():
    with open('test.csv') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip("\n")
            column = line.split(",")
            if column[1] == column[2]:
                print("Woohoo, {0} is equal to {1}!".format(column[1], column[2]))

do_work()
```

That's how to compare column 2 to column 3 in the same csv, so build off of that.  Open up two handlers and compare across CSV's.